# How to setup php server for braintree

Tags: braintree

Pls how can I setup php server for braintree? Pls anybody can help here, I am developing a an android app and I want to integrate payment on it.I have the code for the client side. In order to setup the server side is now the major problem. Also is ssl compulsory for the webserver I want to use?

Pls I need your guide here. Thanks

Comment: This is way too broad. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Thanks  Carcigenicate . Firstly is ssl needed on my website ? I want to setup my web server for braintree  their. If ssl is not compulsory. Pls I need a code for the server side of the braintree using php

Comment: @Emmy SSL and TLS 1.2 is [required](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/best-practices/#transport-layer-security) for production. It's not necessary for [testing](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/best-practices/#testing) as long as you're not incorporating the PayPal button in webviews. That being said, it's still recommended for a realistic test environment.

Comment: thanks for your response  hollabaq